# Manipulating char arrays in C - Empty pointers?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm coming from a long experience from Java, so this makes no sense what so ever to me right now. I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

#include "uname.h"

int main(void) {

    char *var; 
    getKernelVersion(&var);

    printf("%s\n", var);
    return 0;

}

int getKernelVersion(char **ver) {

    struct utsname buf;
    int errno;
    errno = uname(&buf);
    strcpy(*ver, buf.release);

    return errno;
}
```

The first line I'm confused about is `char *var`, it is a pointer that points to ... ehm .. nowhere? Where does it point to?

The next thing that is confusing is the double pointer in the function arguments `char **ver`. It creates a pointer that points to ... nothing?!

Thenn, `strcpy(*ver, buf.release)` somehow magically copies buf.release, which is this

```
struct utsname {
    char sysname[];    /* Operating system name (e.g., "Linux") */
    char nodename[];   /* Name within "some implementation-defined
                                     network" */
    char release[];    /* Operating system release (e.g., "2.6.28") */
    char version[];    /* Operating system version */
    char machine[];    /* Hardware identifier */
    #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
        char domainname[]; /* NIS or YP domain name */
    #endif
};
```

Into the empty pointer `*var` somehow, and then i print out `var` which now magically contains the value of `buf.release`.

How come I did not have to allocate memory for `char *var`? How does it hold the string I need? What is life right now?

Comment: It is just wrong (and works by coincidence). `strcpy(*ver, buf.release);` -->> `*ver = strdup(buf.release);`

Comment: I hate C/C++ so much. It sacrifices so much for sheer performance. And it's a shame it is the only feasible language for writing operating systems.

Comment: Nothing is sacrified. You just should not make any misstakes. And yes: C++ is terrible.

Comment: `I'm coming from a long experience from Java,` You mean: more than five years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm coming from a long experience from Java [...]. The first line I'm confused about is `char *var`, it is a pointer that points to ... ehm .. nowhere? Where does it point to?

The value of an automatic variable with no initializer (such as `var`) is indeterminate until a value is assigned to it.  Until then, you don't know where the value of `var` points, and your program exhibits undefined behavior if it does anything that relies on that value.  This is really not so different from Java.  Consider:

```
class MyClass {
    public void example(void) {
        char[] var;

        // Line 1
        // ...
    }
}
```

What array does `var` reference at line 1?  Java has no answer -- it does not even allow you to ask the question.  If you try to write code that depends on the value of `var` before it is initialized, the compiler rejects it.  C is a little less protective, but otherwise the two languages are very similar in this regard.

> The next thing that is confusing is the double pointer in the function arguments char **ver. It creates a pointer that points to ... nothing?!

It doesn't *create* anything.  It specifies the parameter's type (and therefore the expected type for the corresponding argument wherever the function is called) to be a pointer to a pointer.  This is again not much different from Java.  Given ...

```
    public void example2(Object[] objects) {
        // ...
    }
```

... the method parameter `objects` does not *create* anything; it just refers to whatever value is passed as an argument.  The C version is not particularly strange once you grasp the fact that pointers are *values*, just as much as `int`s and `double`s are.  They can be passed as parameters and stored in memory.

Furthermore, when a pointer is stored in memory -- perhaps memory associated with a variable or an array element -- that memory has an address, and that address can itself be represented as another (different) pointer value.  In your case, the type of that pointer is `char **`, which you can express in English as "pointer to pointer to char".

> Thenn, `strcpy(*ver, buf.release)` somehow magically copies `buf.release` [...]
>   Into the empty pointer *var somehow

There are two things going on here, but no magic.

**Thing 1**:  The argument corresponding to function parameter `ver` is `&var` -- the address of variable `var`.  The type of this pointer matches the declared type of `ver`.  Since `ver == &var`, applying the derferencing operator (`*`) to `ver` yields an expression that designates the same object that `var` does.  Thus writing to `*ver` modifies the value of `var` in the caller.

That has no direct analog in Java, but consider this code:

```
public void example3a(List<Integer> list) {
    list.append(42);
}

public void example3b(void) {
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    example3a(myList);
    assert(myList.contains(42));
}
```

Method `example3a()` is able to modify the contents of the `List` passed to it.  Or actually, the `List` whose *reference* is passed to it, by value.  Java and C alike have strictly pass-by-value semantics, but you can pass a reference (Java) or a pointer (C) by value to enable the referenced / pointed-to thing to be accessed and modified in a way that the caller can later observe.

**Thing 2**: the code is erroneous.  As you observed, `var` is not initialized in the caller.  The usual reason to pass a pointer to it to a function would be to enable the function to *assign a value* to it, indirectly via the pointer.  But the function does not do that.  Instead, it attempts to copy data into the pointed-to space, but that uses the indeterminate value that `var` still contains, and therefore yields undefined behavior.

UB *can* manifest as more or less anything, including what the programmer intended, so the code may seem to work.  It is nevertheless wrong, as is any program that exhibits UB.  You cannot rely on it to work on any given call, not even if it seemed to behave as intended on a previous call within the same run of the program.  The programmer's apparent intent would be better implemented like this:

```
int getKernelVersion(char **ver) {
    struct utsname buf;
    int errno;

    errno = uname(&buf);
    *ver = strdup(buf.release);

    return errno;
}
```

Note the difference here: an *assignment* to `*ver`, which also sets the value of `var` in the caller.

> How come I did not have to allocate memory for char *var?

Excellent question.  In fact, in the original version of the program, you *did* need to allocate memory for `*var`.  The program exhibits UB because you failed to do so.

> How does it hold the string I need?

The `strcpy()` call exhibits undefined behavior.  Whether `*var` holds the string you need after the call is undefined.  If it appears to do, then you lucked out.  Or perhaps you could say you got *un*lucky: a nice segmentation fault would have clued you in that there was a problem with the program.

> What is life right now?

Life is like a box of chocolates: you never know which one you're going to get.  Kinda the same as UB, actually.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Truly amazing! I owe you a cold one fam.

Comment: Its awesomely explained (y)

Answer (score 1):

> The first line I'm confused about is char *var, it is a pointer that points to ... ehm .. nowhere? Where does it point to?

It is *uninitialized*. Not that it points to nowhere, it actually does not point anywhere.

Nevertheless, its (unexisting) value is used next in the function, which is an error.

> The next thing that is confusing is the double pointer in the function arguments char **ver. It creates a pointer that points to ... nothing?!

No, it is a pointer that points to a pointer (that points to a char). In your case, it is bound (since it is a function argument) to point to that very `var`; since it is not a pointer-to-constant, the original value pointed (in your case, `var`, a pointer to a char) can be changed, for example (to point to another char). This is one of the eldest C idioms, having function argument(s) to point to the objects that are expected to hold additional function return value(s).

> How come I did not have to allocate memory for char *var? How does it hold the string I need?

And does it? Have you actually tested the code?

Comment: Yes, i have. It prints "4.6.3-t61" to the console as it sould!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you find

```
char *getKernelVersion();
```

more intuitive. The problem with that approach is that the you can only signal error by returning `NULL`. What if you want to return more specific information on the error?

```
int getKernelVersion(char **ver);
```

On the other hand takes a pointer to a pointer (i.e. a pointer passed by reference) and sets it to the string in question. The return type is left for use as an error code.

the `uname(2)` system call works the same way. It returns an error code and receives the `struct` it needs to populate by reference.

---

The use of `strcpy` is erroneous though as your noticed. It copies over bytes to a unspecified location causing undefined behavior. Instead it should say `*ver = strdup(buf.release);`

Comment: So strcpy just copied the bytes anywhere it could into memory?

Comment: @a3f buf is a stack variable which would be destroyed soon after functions return?

Comment: @Mazhar stack variables aren't destroyed. This would be really inefficient, instead the stack pointer is adjusted and the data is left as is till it's overwritten by a new stack frame.

Comment: @Gala Not anywhere, it just so happened that a previous stack frame left a bit pattern which interpreted as a memory address pointed to accessible writable memory.

Comment: @a3f still any thing could happen. Gala better use dynamic allocation rather then static.

Comment: He doesn't use any allocation at all. Just undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> The first line I'm confused about is char *var, it is a pointer that
>   points to ... ehm .. nowhere? Where does it point to?

For now pointer `var` is not pointing to somewhere

> The next thing that is confusing is the double pointer in the function
>   arguments char **ver. It creates a pointer that points to ...
>   nothing?!

Double pointer `**` is the pointing to empty pointer you made above i.e. `var`. In other word, `**` is the stack address of `var`.

> Into the empty pointer *var somehow, and then i print out var which
>   now magically contains the value of buf.release.

If you really check the program working, Seemingly, may be `strcpy()` internally checks and allocate memory to `var` if its `null` but I am not fully sure.

> How come I did not have to allocate memory for char *var? How does it
>   hold the string I need? What is life right now?

So if `strcpy()` allocates the memory to `var` then then there is no wonder at all.

Comment: Nice explanation. There is also a black hole for me now. How can I assign a struct member to a char, non pointer, so i can modify it? char a[] = buf.release is a no-no?

Comment: a[] is not a simple char it is an array, if you mention its name only like 'a' it is already a pointer to first element of character array i.e a[0].  So you can assign some pointer (release) like this  a = buf.release. Both  'a' and 'release' are pointers.  But again buf is a local variable. which will be destroyed. You better malloc the var or buf

Comment: How can i then declare a simple, non pointer char array from buf.release?, on which i can access elements? The drill is to split the release string.

Comment: Remember array name is always pointer to first element of array. So you can't really separate these things but if you hate pointers ( which are cool you will realize later ) you can use loops like for loop. 

char array[20] = ''; // empty array
char src_array[]="2.34.5" ; // array of size equal to length of "2.34.5" 

for ( int i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i ++) 
array[i] = src_array[i]; 

But above thing is not recommended at all. You can simple achive by doing this 

array = src_array;

Comment: I did not understand any of that. lol. Let me rephrase my question. I want to do the following: char somechar = buf.release[0]; I want to access the characters in release one by one. Got it?

How?

Comment: You are doing just correct already :) I did the same in for loop. you just need to read the comment using some .doc file etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115660/discussion-between-gala-and-mazhar).